# Get the follower Count in Django

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am currently trying to get the total amount of followers a user has and also the total amount of users following a particular user.I want to return an integer value but cant seem to get it right. Is there anything i need to add in my models.py or in my views.py?

I tried

```
UserLink.objects.filter(from_user=User).values('to_user').count
```

but it keeps returning zero (0)

```
Models.py 

class UserLink(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following_set')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower_set')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
```

I am new to django and any help is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is a function, which must be called.  So put a pair of parentheses after it.

Another potential problem here is your passing `User` into the filter function in views.py.  You want to pass in an **instance** of the class User, not the class itself.  So you'd want something like this:

```
UserLink.objects.filter(from_user=whichuser).values('to_user').count()
```

where the variable `whichuser` is an instance of the `User` class.

As for the task you're trying accomplish, I'm not sure how "the total amount of followers a user has" is different from "the total amount of users following a particular user".  To get either one you'd want the following:

```
UserLink.objects.filter(to_user=whichuser).count()
```